# How to get sorted struct into another struct/dictionary using swift3?

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm trying to create alphabetic sections in my TableView, so far I'v managed to get my database into struct and get the fist letter of every name from my database and sort it for the section header.
My problem is that I don't get the sorted variable into the another struct and show it in the table.

My structs:

```
struct CrimesInfo {

    let name: String
    let detail: String
    let time: String


    init(name:String, detail: String, time: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.detail = detail
        self.time = time
    }

    init(fromResultSet: FMResultSet) {
        self.init(
            name: fromResultSet.string(forColumn: "Name"),
            detail: fromResultSet.string(forColumn: "Detail"),
            time: fromResultSet.string(forColumn: "Time")
        )

    }
}

struct CrimeNameSection {

    var firstLetter: Character
    var crimes: [CrimesInfo]

    init(title: Character, objects: [CrimesInfo]) {
        firstLetter = title
        crimes = objects
    }
}
```

My database store in struct 'CrimesInfo', after the sorting I want to insert it into the struct 'CrimeNameSection' (title: the first letter of 'name', objects: the rest of the data accordingly).

My code:

```
class SectionData {

    var crimeInfo : [CrimesInfo] = []

    func getCrimesData() {
        crimeInfo = ModelManager.getInstance().getAllCrimeInfo() // get the database into the struct
    }

    func getSectionFromData() -> [CrimeNameSection] { // get the fisrt letter of 'name', sort it and get in the another struct
        var crimeIndex = [Character: [CrimesInfo]]()
        var CrimeSections = [CrimeNameSection]()
        for crime in crimeInfo {
            if let firstCharacter = crime.name.characters.first {
                if crimeIndex[firstCharacter] == nil {
                    crimeIndex[firstCharacter] = [crime]
                } else {
                    crimeIndex[firstCharacter]?.append(crime)
            }
        }
    }

    let sortedIndex = crimeIndex.sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 } // type: [(key: Character, value:[CrimesInfo])]

    for key in sortedIndex { // get the sorted data into struct 'CrimeNameSection'
        let sortedSections = CrimeNameSection(title: sortedIndex(key), objects: sortedIndex(value)) // error: 'Use of unresolved identifier 'value'
    }

    CrimeSections.append(sortedSections)

    return CrimeSections
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you hate indentation?

Comment: lol. I don't hate it and I always using it in my code but when I posted this question everything got messy so I leaved it that way. Thank you for the observation

Comment: Well can you fix it?

Comment: What do you need `CrimeNameSection` for? Why not just keep a dictionary from `Character` to `[CrimeInfo]`?

Comment: Fixed it. I think you right about using the dictionary instead of the second struct but I want to present the data in tableView and it's easier with struct for me. can you show me how you would do it?

Comment: Wheredo you need to use this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a list of `CrimeInfo`

```
let crimes = [
    CrimesInfo(name: "ba", detail: "", time: ""),
    CrimesInfo(name: "aa", detail: "", time: ""),
    CrimesInfo(name: "ab", detail: "", time: ""),
    CrimesInfo(name: "ca", detail: "", time: ""),
    CrimesInfo(name: "ac", detail: "", time: ""),
    CrimesInfo(name: "bb", detail: "", time: ""),
]
```

you can write

```
let sections: [CrimeNameSection] = crimes
    .sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
    .reduce([CrimeNameSection]()) { result, crime -> [CrimeNameSection] in
        let crimeFirstLetter = crime.name.characters.first ?? " "

        guard var index = result.index(where: { $0.firstLetter == crimeFirstLetter }) else {
            let newSection = CrimeNameSection(title: crimeFirstLetter, objects: [crime])
            return result + [newSection]
        }

        var result = result
        var section = result[index]
        section.crimes.append(crime)
        result[index] = section
        return result
    }
```

and you get this output

```
print(sections[0])
// CrimeNameSection(firstLetter: "a", crimes: [CrimesInfo(name: "aa", detail: "", time: ""), CrimesInfo(name: "ab", detail: "", time: ""), CrimesInfo(name: "ac", detail: "", time: "")])

print(sections[1])
// CrimeNameSection(firstLetter: "b", crimes: [CrimesInfo(name: "ba", detail: "", time: ""), CrimesInfo(name: "bb", detail: "", time: "")])

print(sections[2])
// CrimeNameSection(firstLetter: "c", crimes: [CrimesInfo(name: "ca", detail: "", time: "")])
```

### Just a note

Let's look at your `CrimeNameSection`.

```
struct CrimeNameSection {

    var firstLetter: Character
    var crimes: [CrimesInfo]

    init(title: Character, objects: [CrimesInfo]) {
        firstLetter = title
        crimes = objects
    }
}
```

you named the second param of the initializer `objects`. This is semantically wrong since CrimeInfo is not an object, is a value.

Why don't you simply remove the initializer and the the struct to expose the memberwise initializer? Look

```
struct CrimeNameSection {
    var firstLetter: Character
    var crimes: [CrimesInfo]
}
```

now you can write

```
CrimeNameSection(firstLetter: "a", crimes: crimes)
```

### Update

This is how you populate your table view

```
class Table: UITableViewController {

    var sections: [CrimeNameSection] = ...

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].crimes.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let crime: CrimesInfo = sections[indexPath.section].crimes[indexPath.row]

        // TODO: use crime to populate your cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.... it worked and I changed the struct as you pointed in your note. I have another question: how can I access the second struct? I want to show the data in TableView I mean inside the the override func tableView cellForRowAt indexPath?

Comment: Thank you, run smoothly and the code really look aesthetic, again thank you... it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I suggest against `CrimeNameSection`. Just use a dictionary from `Character` to `[CrimeInfo]`. It'll be much easier to work with.

```
extension Array {
    func groupBy<Key>(_ keyGenerator: (Element) -> Key)
        -> [Key: [Element]] {
        var result = [Key: [Element]]()

        for element in self {
            let key = keyGenerator(element)
            var array = result[key] ?? []
            array.append(element)
            result[key] = array
        }

        return result
    }
}

let crimes = [
    CrimesInfo(name: "ba", detail: "", time: ""),
    CrimesInfo(name: "aa", detail: "", time: ""),
    CrimesInfo(name: "ab", detail: "", time: ""),
    CrimesInfo(name: "ca", detail: "", time: ""),
    CrimesInfo(name: "ac", detail: "", time: ""),
    CrimesInfo(name: "bb", detail: "", time: ""),
]

let crimesByInitial = crimes.groupBy{ $0.name.characters.first! }
```

result:

```
[
    "b": [
        CrimesInfo(name: "ba", detail: "", time: ""),
        CrimesInfo(name: "bb", detail: "", time: "")
    ],
    "a": [
        CrimesInfo(name: "aa", detail: "", time: ""),
        CrimesInfo(name: "ab", detail: "", time: ""),
        CrimesInfo(name: "ac", detail: "", time: "")
    ],
    "c": [
         CrimesInfo(name: "ca", detail: "", time: "")
    ]
]
```

Comment: To act as a `UITableViewDataSource` you need to retrieve sections by index. With a dictionary you would have to sort the keys on each `numberOfRowsInSection` or `cellForRowAt` call in order to locate the referenced section. An array of sections is a more natural fit.

Comment: @JimMatthews Would you mind suggesting an edit, as you deem appropriate?

Comment: Your code looks good for generating a dictionary, but seems a mismatch for a `UITableViewDataSource`. The answer by @appzYourLife, above, shows how nicely an array serves as the data structure for a `UITableViewDataSource`.